# Значение referer, полученное get-запросом

Tags: http, iframe

Чему равен referer, полученный get-запросом из IFRAME в домене, отличном от запрашиваемого в get? Например, посещаем сайт с IFRAME, в котором есть запрос к другому домену. Какой referer получит сервер другого сайта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тот, с которого произведен запрос. Если из фрейма - получит referer фрейма, если извне - основного сайта.

Comment: Если на сайте mysite.com фрейм с сайтом yousite.com, сервер yousite.com получит yousite.com в качестве referef?

Comment: А, в этом плане. Фрейм получает в реферер родителя, так же, как если с родителя перейти на сайт фрейма по ссылке. Т.е. в вашем случае yousite.com получит реферер mysite.com.